# Resizable Modal Popup

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to make a modal window resizable by clicking increase and decrease icons. The modal should also be positioned at the middle of the screen after each ***`increase/decrease`*** click.

So far, only increase is working. Can anyone shed light on what I am doing wrong?

```
this.increaseModal = function () {
        var maxHeight = ($(window).height() * 90) / 100;
        var maxWidth = ($(window).width() * 90) / 100;
        var height = ($(window).height() * 10) / 100;
        var width = ($(window).width() * 10) / 100;
        if ($('.modal-content').height() <= maxHeight - 100) {
            $('.modal-content').height($('.modal-content').height() + height);
            increaseHeightCount = increaseHeightCount + 1;
        }
        if ($('.modal-content').width() <= maxWidth - 100) {
            $('.modal-content').width($('.modal-content').width() + width);
            increaseWidthCount = increaseWidthCount + 1;
        }
        $('.modal-dialog').draggable();
        $('#myModal').addClass('outPopUp');
    }
```

```
this.decreaseModal = function () {
    var maxHeight = ($(window).height() * 90) / 100;
    var maxWidth = ($(window).width() * 90) / 100;
    var height = ($(window).height() * 10) / 100;
    var width = ($(window).width() * 10) / 100;
    if (increaseWidthCount > 0) {
        $('.modal-content').width($('.modal-content').width() - width);
        increaseWidthCount = increaseWidthCount - 1;
    }
    if (increaseHeightCount > 0) {
        $('.popup').height($('.popup').height() - height);
        increaseHeightCount = increaseHeightCount - 1;
    }
}
```

`outPopUp` is the class where I override bootstrap css for changing the modal window position.

As far as I can see in the DOM explorer, .popup is not assigned to the element and hence increase/decrease height is not working.

Comment: hi, is the increase working? because at the top, you've said is working but at the bottom you've said is not working. Can you also show your html for the popup? thanks!

Comment: Further to what @dsg wrote, please create a [fiddle](http://jsbin.com/) or (even better) add a snippet to your question so we could see the problem.  See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: on clicking the increase icon, modal width is increasing.. not height.
decrease does not work at all and the positioning does not change to middle of screen.

Comment: here is the fiddle i just created https://jsfiddle.net/569n1mh4/

Comment: Is it just me or the modal can not be draggable or resizable at all?

Comment: hmm its not working. i will update it

Comment: Just update your question. Don't put your fiddle link in comments. Not everyone can see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JQuery already has the functions you need to accomplish this.

```js
$('.modal-content').resizable({
    //alsoResize: ".modal-dialog",
    //minHeight: 150
});
$('.modal-dialog').draggable();

$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('.modal-body').css({
        'max-height':'100%'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/p7o2mkg4/

Comment: Just for clarification, this functionality is part of the jQuery UI library.